# MATLAB removing rows which has duplicates in sequence

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to remove the rows which has duplicates in sequence. I have only 2 possible values which are 0 and 1. I have nXm which n shows possible number of bits and m is not important for my question. My goal is to find an matrix which is nX(m-a). The rows a which has the property which includes duplicates in sequence. For example:

My matrix is :

```
A=[0 1 0 1 0 1;
   0 0 0 1 1 1;
   0 0 1 0 0 1;
   0 1 0 0 1 0;
   1 0 0 0 1 0]
```

I want to remove the rows has t duplicates in sequence for 0. In this question let's assume t is 3. So I want the matrix which:

```
B=[0 1 0 1 0 1;
   0 0 1 0 0 1; 
   0 1 0 0 1 0]
```

2nd and 5th rows are removed.

I probably need to use diff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to remove rows of `A` that contain at least `t` zeros in sequence.

How about a single line?

```
B = A(~any(conv2(1,ones(1,t),2*A-1,'valid')==-t, 2),:);
```

*How this works*:

1. Transform `A` to bipolar form (`2*A-1`)
2. Convolve each row with a sequence of `t` ones (`conv2(...)`)
3. Keep only rows for which the convolution does not contain `-t` (`~any(...))`. The presence of `-t` indicates a sequence of `t` zeros in the corresponding row of `A`.

To remove rows that contain at least `t` *ones*, just change `-t` to `t`:

```
B = A(~any(conv2(1,ones(1,t),2*A-1,'valid')==t, 2),:);
```

Comment: It is certain that your answer is very clever :) But I did not understand it. How can it for 1's?

Comment: @toygankılıç Sorry, what do you mean "How can it for 1's"?

Comment: My question is only for duplicate of 0. How it can be written for 1's.

Comment: Very clever use of `conv2` here +1. I used your logic to generalize this for `any` consecutive numbers instead of 0 with `im2col`

Answer (score 3):

How about an approach using strings?  This is certainly not as fast as Luis Mendo's method where you work directly with the numerical array, but it's thinking a bit outside of the box.  The basis of this approach is that I consider each row of `A` to be a unique string, and I can search each string for occurrences of a string of 0s by regular expressions.

```
A=[0 1 0 1 0 1;
   0 0 0 1 1 1;
   0 0 1 0 0 1;
   0 1 0 0 1 0;
   1 0 0 0 1 0];
t = 3;

B = sprintfc('%s', char('0' + A));   
ind = cellfun('isempty', regexp(B, repmat('0', [1 t])));
B(~ind) = [];
B = double(char(B) - '0');
```

We get:

```
B =
     0     1     0     1     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1     0
```

---

## Explanation

- Line 1: Convert each line of the matrix `A` into a string consisting of 0s and 1s.  Each line becomes a cell in a cell array.  This uses the undocumented function [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) to facilitate this cell array conversion.
- Line 2: I use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to find any occurrences of a string of 0s that is `t` long.  I first use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to create a search string that is full of 0s and is `t` long.  After, I determine if each line in this cell array contains this sequence of characters (i.e. `000....`).  The function [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) helps us perform regular expressions and returns the locations of any matches for each cell in the cell array.  Alternatively, you can use the function [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) for more recent versions of MATLAB to speed up the computation, but I chose `regexp` so that the solution is compatible with most MATLAB distributions out there.

  Continuing on, the output of `regexp/strfind` is a cell array of elements where each cell reports the locations of where we found the particular string.  If we have a match, there should be at least one location that is reported at the output, so I check to see if any matches are **empty**, meaning that these are the rows we **don't want to remove**. I want to turn this into a `logical` array for the purposes of removing rows from `A`, and so this is wrapped with a [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) call to determine the cells that are empty.  Therefore, this line returns a `logical` array where a 0 means that remove this row and a 1 means that we don't.
- Line 3: I take the `logical` array from Line 2 and **invert** it because that's what we really want.  We use this inverted array to index into the cell array and remove those strings.
- Line 4: The output is still a cell array, so I convert it back into a character array, and finally back into a numerical array.

Comment: Nice approach! You could also use `ind = cellfun('isempty', strfind(B, repmat('0', [1 t])))`

Comment: @LuisMendo - Cool! I always forget about that. Thanks!

Comment: Hehehe. My point was, regular expressions have a reputation for being slow (I haven't tested that). Maybe `strfind` could speed things up

Comment: @LuisMendo some versions of MATLAB don't have `strfind` which is why I opted for regular expressions. I actually used `strfind` at first!

Comment: @LuisMendo either way you do raise a valid point! This would definitely be slower than most approaches. I'd say this is more academic than anything. Thanks for your vote :)

Comment: You deserved the vote, it's a great answer! Except for [going undocumented](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function), that is :-P

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generalized approach which removes any rows which has given number of consecutive duplicates (not just `zero`. could be any number).

```
t = 3;
row_mask = ~any(all(~diff(reshape(im2col(A,[1 t],'sliding'),t,size(A,1),[]))),3);
out = A(row_mask,:)
```

**Sample Run:**

```
>> A

A =

 0     1     0     1     0     1
 0     0     1     5     5     5    %// consecutive 3 5's
 0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1     0
 1     1     1     0     0     1    %// consecutive 3 1's

>> out

out =

 0     1     0     1     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1     0
```

Comment: Nice use of `im2col`!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks I wouldn't have thought of it if you haven't used `conv2` :P They kind of look similar to me with `im2col` giving intermediate results :D